# DD-WRT: Anyone know how to get RADIUS on the router so I don't need to rely on an external server?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dd-wrt, radius

Ideally, in my environment, the radius server would run on the router, so that we can save power.

Now, I've heard of people using freeRadius, which I've heard is great, but is kind of a pain to set up.   But as long as there are instructions, I can't complain.

So, does anyone know how, or have any links for setting up RADIUS on the DD-WRT router?

for reference:
my router is Netgear WNR3500v2, so it has 64MB of space, most of it free. So there shouldn't be a problem getting freeRadius on there, if that is the chosen RADIUS server.

---

Following a tutorial: I telnetted into my router, did ipkg update, got a bunch of erros "failed to retrieve"

this is what I get when I type df:

```
root@OverMind:~# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                 2048      2048         0 100% /
/dev/mtdblock/4           4160       260      3900   6% /jffs
/dev/mtdblock/4           4160       260      3900   6% /opt
```

so maybe I don't have enough free space?

Comment: i had problems installing radius authenticator on the authenticating device, but it could have been an implementation problem on my part.  freeradius has quite a few dependencies for a full build, so the first thing to look into is compile options with the minimum supported feature set

Comment: here's a decent discussion of cross compiling for ddwrt: http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=3668

Comment: Yes, your root filesystem is full. You need to either reflash with a larger root fs or arrange for some files to be in the read-write filesystem in `/dev/mtdblock/4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's give this one a shot: [A How To for DD-WRT, FreeRadius, and ChilliSpot](http://www.howtoforge.com/wifi_hotspot_setup). The FreeRadius packages exist in OptWare (package 242/3) [OptWare packages](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_list_of_Optware_packages) as apparently stable so you may not be in for too much of a hassle on this one...

Comment: See, I'm trying to get freeRadius on the actual router. =\

Comment: That is what I answered, isn't it? FreeRadius exists in the OptWare repo so just ssh into the router, follow the extensive instructions provided here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Optware#Example_scenario_of_installing_some_packages_on_WRT54GS_.28v1.0_.._v3.0.29 and then "ipkg install freeradius". The Chilli link was for and FR config questions that might arise...

Comment: oh, lol, i'll give it a go

Comment: I ran into a problem, wondering if you know of a solution. Adding to question.

Comment: Update. OptWare is outdated for now, https://github.com/Entware-ng/Entware-ng/wiki/Install-on-DD-WRT is way to go